# I cannot open a Mac OS Mojave on VM Ware virtual machine, and it has data files on it that I need to recover

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I'm Working on `Mac OS Mojave` on `VM Ware Workstation 14 player` but today suddenly my Computer shutdown due to power issue and i couldn't shut down mac. Now when i try to open Mac OS it's crashed every time and it has data files on it that I need to recover. I'm looking for suggestions that might help.

Comment: I think 7-zip can view VMDK files.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its working. Thank you @Mark Setchell

Comment: Have you tried to backup the vmware directory and remove *.VMEM file, then attempt to restart Mojave ?

Comment: No, i have not tried it yet.but i'll try it and let you know soon. Can you please tell me where is *.VMEM file?

Comment: Take a look at this : `https://www.poftut.com/what-is-vmem-virtual-memory-file-and-how-to-use/`, you may want to delete .lck file as well

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to list and extract files from a VMware virtual machine VMDK image using [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org):

E.g.:

```
7z l WindowsXP.vmdk
```

**Sample Output**:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,12 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 14452195328 bytes (14 GiB)

Listing archive: WindowsXP.vmdk

--
Path = WindowsXP.vmdk
Type = VMDK
Physical Size = 14452195328
Method = "monolithicSparse"
Cluster Size = 65536
Headers Size = 2162688
ID = 3f1fc1e8
Name = Windows XP SP3-disk2.vmdk
Comment = # Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=3f1fc1e8
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="monolithicSparse"

# Extent description
RW 33554432 SPARSE "Windows XP SP3-disk2.vmdk"

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
ddb.uuid.image="32b5b00e-2b8f-4101-8c78-afdd93487d01"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="91a31d3b-53a1-45f6-a271-56d7935a473d"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.comment=""

----
Size = 17179869184
Packed Size = 14450032640
--
Path = WindowsXP.mbr
Type = MBR
Physical Size = 17179869184
----
Path = 0.ntfs
Size = 17179836928
File System = NTFS
Offset = 32256
Primary = +
Begin CHS = 0-1-1
End CHS = 1023-254-63
--
Path = 0.ntfs
Type = NTFS
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive
Physical Size = 17179832320
Tail Size = 4608
File System = NTFS 3.1
Cluster Size = 4096
Sector Size = 512
Record Size = 1024
Created = 2013-05-03 12:33:03
ID = 9572501234667689776

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.     43679744     43679744  [SYSTEM]/$MFT
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.         4096         4096  [SYSTEM]/$MFTMirr
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.     23527424     23527424  [SYSTEM]/$LogFile
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$Volume
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.         2560         4096  [SYSTEM]/$AttrDef
2015-11-08 11:50:22 D.HS.                            [SYSTEM]/.
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.       524288       524288  [SYSTEM]/$Bitmap
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.         8192         8192  [SYSTEM]/$Boot
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$BadClus
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$Secure
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HS.       131072       131072  [SYSTEM]/$UpCase
2013-05-03 12:33:03 D.HS.                            [SYSTEM]/$Extend
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HSA            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$Extend/$Quota
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HSA            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$Extend/$ObjId
2013-05-03 12:33:03 ..HSA            0            0  [SYSTEM]/$Extend/$Reparse
2014-05-09 10:46:47 ....A        86144        90112  Documents and Settings/Person/Application Data/Dropbox/instance1/l/536cb1a7
2013-05-29 23:37:50 D....                            WINDOWS
2015-11-07 15:25:40 D....                            WINDOWS/system32
2013-05-03 12:05:12 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/config
2015-06-01 17:41:13 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/drivers
2013-05-03 12:41:52 D....                            WINDOWS/system
2013-05-03 12:35:48 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/ras
2013-05-03 12:00:39 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/spool
2013-05-03 12:33:10 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/spool/drivers
2013-05-03 12:33:10 D....                            WINDOWS/system32/spool/drivers/w32x86
```